# Client cant spawn network objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking

Here is my code :

```
[ServerRpc(RequireOwnership = false)]

public void ShootServerRpc()
{
    if (!IsOwner)
    {
        return;
    }
    if (!grounded)
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
            touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position);

            Vector2 direction = touchPosition - anchoredLaunchPoint.position;
            float angle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.y, direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
            Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle + -rotationCorection, Vector3.forward);
            anchoredLaunchPoint.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(anchoredLaunchPoint.rotation, rotation, 100f * Time.fixedDeltaTime);

            GameObject bulletObject = Instantiate(bullet, anchoredLaunchPoint.position, Quaternion.identity);
            bulletObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(anchoredLaunchPoint.up * shootPower, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            bulletObject.GetComponent<NetworkObject>().Spawn(true);

        }
    }
    
}`
```

its a simple shooting script but it doesnt work as intended. Ive seen some tutorials on how to do it and they all did the same thing add server rpc and you're good.

Comment: so what happens?

Comment: @RandRandom well yes ... but what speaks against asking for more clarity?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you wouldn't want to depend on the user input, ownership and grounded state on the server ;)

Have in mind that a `ServerRpc` - as the name says is sent and only executed **on the server!**

The usage of those "magic" attributes obfuscates this a bit but what happens is basically

```
Local client                          Server

Calls ShootServerRpc  
(NOT executed but)   ---ServerRpc---> Executes ShootServerRpc
```

You rather want to handle those locally and only dispatch the call itself to the server somewhat like e.g.

```
public void Shoot()
{
    if (!IsOwner)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (!grounded)
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
            touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position);

            Vector2 direction = touchPosition - anchoredLaunchPoint.position;
            float angle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.y, direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
            Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle + -rotationCorection, Vector3.forward);
            anchoredLaunchPoint.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(anchoredLaunchPoint.rotation, rotation, 100f * Time.fixedDeltaTime);

            ShootServerRpc(anchoredLaunchPoint.position, anchoredLaunchPoint.up * shootPower);
        }
    }
}

[ServerRpc]
private void ShootServerRpc(Vector3 position, Vector3 shootDirection)
{
    var bulletObject = Instantiate(bullet, position, Quaternion.identity);
    bulletObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(shootDirection, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    bulletObject.GetComponent<NetworkObject>().Spawn(true);
}
```